# let to right the combo box in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a combo box which is for age in `html` I want to change it from left to right side to right to left side. here is the code:

```
                            <div class="form-group" dir=rtl><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">سن</label>



>  <div class="col-sm-2"><select class="form-control m-b" 
> name=Location>
>                                     <option></option>
>                                     <option>18-25</option>
>                                     <option>26-35</option>
>                                     <option>36-45</option>
>                                     <option>46 بالاتر</option>
>                                 </select>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap, try this https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl